# How to make the tab character 4 spaces instead of 8 spaces in nano?

Tags: tabs, terminal, indentation, nano

When I press TAB in `nano` editor, the cursor will jump with 8 spaces like this:

```
def square(x):
        return x * x
def cube(y):
        return y * y * y
```

how can I set the tab stop width to 4 spaces to display like this:

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
def cube(y):
    return y * y * y
```

Comment: Nano is a pretty basic editor. There's a good chance it just doesn't support this.

Comment: umm not only in nano, but it also indent by 8 spaces when I use python interpreter in Terminal.

Comment: This is answered on SuperUser, and should be closed as duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/110421/tab-character-width-in-terminal

Comment: @millimoose, changing the tab stops in the terminal doesn't affect nano. This question should be specifically about nano or about setting the tab stops for Python, but not about both and not about interactively setting the tab stops with the `tab` command, which doesn't affect all programs.

Answer (score 349):

If you use nano with a language like **python** (as in your example) it's also a good idea to convert tabs to spaces.

Edit your **~/.nanorc** file (or create it) and add:

```
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
```

If you already got a file with tabs and want to convert them to spaces i recommend the `expand`command (shell):

```
expand -4 input.py > output.py
```

Comment: I'm using mint and when I set tabsize from 8 to 4 in /etc/nanorc and go back to the file, I'm still getting 8 spaces in the tab, I even tried to copy that nanorc file to ~/. but that doesn't work, closed and reopened terminal, but still I can't get 4 spaces on the tab unless I use nano -T4. Thanks

Comment: @Alex double check that your file starts with a dot `.nanorc` not `nanorc`. This must be placed in your users home-directory, i.e. `/home/your-username/.nanorc`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating another .nanorc different from the one in /etc, placed it in the home dir and that worked. This are the only 3 lines I included in the new .nanorc for anyone interested: set nowrap, set tabsize 4 and set tabstospaces

Comment: If this is your toy, you can make this change available system wide, just edit the global file `/etc/nanorc`. There are a few other options there that you may enjoy.

Comment: Hi @Alexey . This Linux Shell command works for all files, but make sure to specify another output-file, otherwise your file will be emptied.

Comment: Sorry, i meant to ask if the indentation could be set exclusively for `*.py` files.

Comment: I'm really glad you mentioned that `.nanorc` can be in the home directory instead of `/etc/...`, which doesn't seem to exist on Termux.

Comment: No it's not a good idea to convert tabs to spaces in Python. Enjoy reading someone else's code indented by 1 space... or by 13 spaces...

Comment: @Jeyekomon check out the python [PEP 8 Style Guide - Tabs or Spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces). A tabsize of 4 is the most common indentation for python. You should avoid ppl who are writing python code with 1 space or 13 space indentation anyway.

Comment: Don't do `expand -4 input.py > input.py` or your code will disappear. Probably some peculiarity with streams.

Answer (score 125):

## Command-line flag

From `man nano`:

```
-T cols (--tabsize=cols)
    Set the size (width) of a tab to cols columns.
    The value of cols must be greater than 0. The default value is 8.
-E (--tabstospaces)
    Convert typed tabs to spaces.
```

For example, to set the tab size to 4, replace tabs with spaces, and edit the file "foo.txt", you would run the command:

```
nano -ET4 foo.txt
```

## Config file

From `man nanorc`:

```
set tabsize n
    Use a tab size of n columns. The value of n must be greater than 0.
    The default value is 8.
set/unset tabstospaces
    Convert typed tabs to spaces.
```

Edit your `~/.nanorc` file (create it if it does not exist), and add those commands to it. For example:

```
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
```

Nano will use these settings by default whenever it is launched, but command-line flags will override them.

Comment: umm... i can't find the .nanorc file in ~/ directory

Comment: Ok never mind. I find     nanorc in     /etc directory. thanks though

Comment: If it does not exist, you can create it.

Comment: @FallenSatan, generally you should avoid editing /etc/nanorc, unless you need to perform system-wide customizations. Create ~/.nanorc if it doesn't already exist and put your customizations there.

Comment: @FallenSatan, please consider marking this as the accepted answer if it adequately answered your question.

Comment: Note that in the above answer you need to add the line "set tabsize 4", not "set tabspace 4"

Comment: sudo nano will not take ~/.nanorc for an obvious reason; so the command-line flag is a more practical solution to the problem.

Comment: I find it odd that this answer still not has been accepted after over 8 years. It is really informative and gives a great description.

Comment: alias nano='nano -ET4' is also a good memorable alternative

Answer (score 15):

In nano 2.2.6 the line in ~/.nanorc to do this seems to be

```
set tabsize 4
```

Setting tabspace gave me the error:
'Unknown flag "tabspace"'

Answer (score 6):

Setting the tab size in nano

```
cd /etc
ls -a
sudo nano nanorc
```

[image]

Link: https://app.gitbook.com/@cai-dat-chrome-ubuntu-18-04/s/chuaphanloai/setting-the-tab-size-in-nano

Comment: Link is dead, have you got an alternative explanation?

Comment: cd /etc; nano nanorc;

set tabsize 2... unfortunately this is not what is needed for python which expects spaces

Answer (score 4):

For future viewers, there is a line in my /etc/nanorc file close to line 153 that says "set tabsize 8". The word might need to be tabsize instead of tabspace. After I replaced 8 with 4 and uncommented the line, it solved my problem.

Comment: Are you [Caleb Curry](https://www.youtube.com/@codebreakthrough) by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to set tab size 4 at nano. There are some easy steps to do that:

1. Go to the 'etc' directory(folder) from the home directory.

```sh
cd /etc
```

2. There is a file name 'nanorc', need to edit it. You can see the lists of the files by running `ls -a`.
   Enter the file with your favorite editor like nano or gedit etc.

```sh
sudo nano nanorc
```

3. You need to find out a line `set tabsize 8`.By default, the tab size is set to 8 spaces. There are around 300 lines.
   You can run this command to search the position of the line without scrolling. To do that **exit**(ctrl+Z) from nano and run

```sh
grep -n "set tabsize" nanorc
```

in my case, it's the 159th line. The output is:

```
159:# set tabsize 8
```

4. Now open the 'nanorc' file again(shown in step 2).
   Go to the line number which was found in step 3.
   In nano to see line numbers in editor press **alt+shift+3**.
   You may find a line like this: `# set tabsize 8`

Uncomment the line(remove `#`) and put 4 instead of 8 and save it(ctrl+o then press enter).
[image]

And then you are done.
-- It's helpful to set tab size 4 if you use nano for python scripts.

> > In case it doesn't work perfectly, uncomment the next line also. In my case line 162, which is ' **# set tabstospaces**  '

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who may stumble across this old question ...

There is one thing that I think needs to be addressed.

`~/.nanorc` is used to apply your user specific settings to nano, so if you are editing files that require the use of `sudo nano` for permissions then this is not going to work.

When using `sudo` your custom user configuration files will not be loaded when opening a program, as you are not running the program from your account so none of your configuration changes in `~/.nanorc` will be applied.

If this is the situation you find yourself in (wanting to run `sudo nano` *and* use your own config settings) then you have three options :

- using command line flags when running `sudo nano`
- editing the `/root/.nanorc` file
- editing the `/etc/nanorc` global config file

Keep in mind that `/etc/nanorc` is a global configuration file and as such it affects all users, which may or may not be a problem depending on whether you have a multi-user system.

Also, user config files will override the global one, so if you were to edit `/etc/nanorc` and `~/.nanorc` with different settings, when you run `nano` it will load the settings from `~/.nanorc` but if you run `sudo nano` then it will load the settings from `/etc/nanorc`.

Same goes for `/root/.nanorc` this will override `/etc/nanorc` when running `sudo nano`

Using flags is probably the best option unless you have a **lot** of options.

Answer (score 1):

For MAC Nanos, you should edit the "~/nanorc" configuration file in preference to the "~/.nanorc" configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set tab size for a certain syntax type, e.g. `python`, independent of `tabsize` and `tabstospaces`, there's a function `tabgives`. A `nanorc` would have it already preset like this:

```
# extendsyntax python tabgives "  "
```

Just uncomment it and type the desired tab inside the quotes.